# Derivation of Parasitic capacitances in MOSFETs using Cadence Virtuoso

Tags: mosfet, cadence

I have to design a circuit to derive the n-channel 180nm MOSFET gate-to-drain, and gate-to-source capacitances in Cadence virtuoso. I have little experience with the software, if someone could describe what the procedure is, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Doesn't Cadence have a support group that this question would be better addressed to?

Comment: If your task was to not do this in Cadence but you were given discrete MOSFETs and had to determine the capacitances in real life, how would you do that? You can use any lab equipment except a capacitance meter. What would you do? Now do the same in Cadence. "Describing the procedure" is a pointless way to learn how to work with Cadence or any simulator, you have to **understand** what you're (going to be) doing first.